# Need to programmatically find the original file of a Visio External Data

Tags: vb.net, vba, visio

I have a need to take modified shape data from shapes on a Visio drawing and insert them back into the original External Data file.  In this case, the external data would be an Excel spreadsheet.

I know how to read the Shape Data and Shapesheet information in VB.

However, I need help in finding the original file and location of the External Data source in VBA.  This is the only thing I'm stuck on.  Any ideas?

EDIT:

I found DataConnection.ConnectionString which gets close but no cigar.  It gives me the full connection string which I could reuse to open the connection to the Excel file if it didn't have 'Mode=Read;' in the string.

Unless someone has a better fix, I guess I could just strip the 'Mode=Read;' out of the returned connection string and see if I can go from there.

Comment: Unless someone has a better ides where to find the path, I would 'strip out' or 'keep only' what is not needed or needed.

Comment: It is not enough to strip "Mode=Read", you most probably will also need also strip down IMEX. Also working with recordsets is not a piece of cake in Visio; it uses old ADODB xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go figure, I spend hours looking for an answer on Google and 10 minutes after posting the question here I figure it out after finding the DataConnection object.

The answer was to use the DataConnection.FileName to return both the path and filename of the original External Data file.

```
For Each win In Visio.ActiveWindow.Windows
  ' The External Data window has ID = 2044
  If win.ID = 2044 Then
    win.Visible = True
    strDataSourceFileName = win.SelectedDataRecordset.DataConnection.FileName
    Exit For
  End If
Next win
```

Comment: Hi ,
Can we change source data file path and refresh the data programmatically ?

Answer (score 0):

You could give a try to Visio addin I recently published (allows write-back):
http://visguy.com/vgforum/index.php?topic=6086

The source code is available at the github:
https://github.com/nbelyh/VisioBackSync